How to call a one Firebase function from another Firebase function using python SDK
I am deploying functions on firebase in python.
I want to call one firebase function from another and pass some data to it.
I have looked into documentation and I cannot find a proper method.
I tried to follow the approach mentioned in
this
forum post.
According to this post cloud functions can call/trigger each other through events.
the first function can publish an event (also pass data in it) and the other can handle that event.
I was able to find the
documentation
for "event handling" but I cannot find any documentation on how to publish an event from a firebase function in python.
I looked at the
admin sdk
for both python and Node.js.
While the node sdk has a
module
for publishing events. python sdk lacks any such functionality.
Am I missing something?
Is there any other method that I can use to achieve this?

If you want to trigger a function programmatically, you should look into writing a pubsub trigger.  You can publish events to a topic with the python client SDK, and receive the payload in the function.
Note that this is not really the same as "calling" a function, as the pubsub trigger can't deliver a response to the calling code.  It's a one-way trigger.  If you want to call a function that delivers a response to the caller, then you will have to write an HTTP trigger instead.
